# Testing PrimeNg data table using jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, primeng, primeng-datatable

How do we write a unit test against primeng filter function in angular using jasmine

**home.component.html**

```
 <input type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Global Filter" (input)="filterGlobal(dt, $event)" >
```

**home.component.ts**

```
  filterGlobal(dt: any, event){
    dt.filterGlobal(event.target.value, 'contains')
  }
```

**home.component.spec.ts**

Comment: Any chance you were able to find a solution to this? I've been looking for a while for something.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this as it took me a while to figure it out.

You need to use fakeAsync() and tick() on your unit test to allow time for everything to update. Use TestBed.configureTestingModule() and TestBed.createComponent() to create your fixture. Then

```
it('name of test', fakeAsync(() => {

  //Arrange
  const mockInputEvent = { target: { value: 'Mock Value' } };

  //Act
  fixture.componentInstance.filterGlobal(mockInputEvent);
  tick(3000);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  
  //Assert
  //Write your assertions here

}));
```